# SAS table from declared variables

Tags: sql, sas, proc

I have some declared variables in a table as follows:

```
data;
a='hello'
b='goodbye'
c='hello again'
run;
```

I want to create a table that now has two columns; 'letter' and 'message' and then populate the table with the data declared above.

create table greetings

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
data Work.Temp;
    a="hello";
    b="good bye";
    c="hello again";
run;

proc transpose data=Work.Temp out=Work.Temp2;
    var a b c;
run;
```